# PHP Form Only Updates Bottom Input for MySQL DataBase Table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm having a problem with my PHP Form that is supposed to update my MySQL Database Table's column for a person's age. The column is called Age. The problem I am getting is when I try to update an age it will not update and displays

```
UPDATE Persons SET Age=Array WHERE FirstName ='Array'
array(13) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" [4]=> string(0) "" [5]=> string(0) "" [6]=> string(0) "" [7]=> string(0) "" [8]=> string(0) "" [9]=> string(0) "" [10]=> string(0) "" [11]=> string(0) "" [12]=> string(3) "544" } Cannot update
```

on the bottom of my page. You can view my page at http://thetotempole.ca/phptester/editpage.php

All the code for my page:

```
<?php
    $hostname = "";//host name
    $dbname = "";//database name
    $username = "";//username you use to login to php my admin
    $password = "";//password you use to login

    //CONNECTION OBJECT
    //This Keeps the Connection to the Databade
    $conn = new MySQLi($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname) or die('Can not connect to database')      
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

//$id=$_GET['FirstName'];

//Create a query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Persons";
//submit the query and capture the result
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$query=getenv(QUERY_STRING);
parse_str($query);
?>
<h2>Update Record <?php echo $sql;?></h2>
<a href="cool.php">Click Here to see the Table Data</a>
<?php $counter = 0; ?>
<form action="" method="post">
<?php

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>

<table border="0" cellspacing="10">
<tr>
<td>Age:</td>
<td><?php echo $row['Age'][$counter];?></td> 
<td><?php echo $row['FirstName'];?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Age[]"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="FirstName[]" value="<?php echo $row['FirstName'];?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><INPUT TYPE="Submit" VALUE="Update the Record" NAME="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
$counter++;   }
?>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){//if the submit button is clicked
$age = $_POST['Age'];
$id = $_POST['FirstName'];

$sql="UPDATE Persons SET Age=$age WHERE FirstName ='$id'";
echo $sql."<br>";
var_dump($_POST[Age]);
$conn->query($sql) or die("Cannot update");//update or error
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I updated the code to my current code.

Comment: I changed $sql="UPDATE Persons SET Age='".$age."' WHERE firstname ='".$id."'"; to $sql="UPDATE Persons SET Age=$age WHERE firstname ='$id'"; and now it only works for the bottom input and it will update it correctly. When I try to update any other inputs it doesn`t work and displays the error "Cannot Update". I would like all inputs to update correctly rather than just the bottom input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the contents of that phpfiddle for easier access:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){ //if ANY submit button has been clicked
    if (is_numeric($_POST['Age'])) {
        $age = (int) $_POST['Age'];
    } elseif ($age == '') {
        $age = (string) 'NULL';
        die('Please go back and enter a valid age.');
    } else { 
        die('Please go back and enter a valid age.');
    }
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['FirstName']);
    $sql="UPDATE Persons SET Age=$age WHERE FirstName ='$id'";
    $conn->query($sql) or die("Cannot update"); //update or error
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM Persons";
$conn->query($sql) or die("Cannot update"); //update or error
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $age = (int) $row['Age'];
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$row['FirstName']);
?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="10">
            <tr>
                <td>Age:</td>
                <td><?php echo $age;?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $id;?></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Age"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="FirstName" value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $id;?></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><INPUT TYPE="Submit" VALUE="Update the Record" NAME="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

if your variable is numeric, then you don't need single quotes for the update statement.  I only corrected Age because I'm not sure about firstname.  Also, PHP doesn't require concatenation of variables into strings surrounded by double quotes.

Hope this helps.

Edit: When you do escape your strings, be sure to use the mysqli version of the function rather than mysql as the latter is deprecated.

Comment: Hey I put your code in and now it only works for the bottom input and it will update it correctly. When I try to update any other inputs it doesn`t work and displays the error "Cannot Update".

Comment: It appears that you are producing a list of inputs in your form that share the same name.  Chances are likely that the multiple instances of the input are overriding one another.  If you put [] on the end of the name, it will feed the results into an array called $_POST[(the input name)] that you can reference to pull your data.  Try putting the brackets in and then var_dump() the $_POST[(whatever)] and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Hey, I changed my input's code to "<td><input type="text" name="Age[]" id="Age"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="FirstName[]" value="<?php echo $row['FirstName'];?>" /></td>" and I added the "var_dump($_POST[Age]);" after "echo $sql."<br>";". My page can be seen at http://thetotempole.ca/phptester/editpage.php

Comment: This appears to be having some issues: UPDATE Persons SET Age=Array WHERE FirstName ='Array'.  SET Age=Array isn't going to work, because the statement won't see Array as a value.  Can you post your actual php code (without connection data) so I can look at it please?  Also, keep in mind that you can enter any unique identifiers inside the brackets after age to make the array associative and easier to pair with the data being displayed.

Comment: I updated the code in my question to what I currently have. Cheers

Comment: This line is the problem: <?php echo $row['Age'];?> Once the [] was added to Age, it became an array, so the line needs to be <?php echo $row['Age'][key];?>. You can put a counter variable starting at 0 in there and increment it with each loop, or you can specify string keys for each element.  For instance, if you made it $row['Age'][$firstName], then the array would use the value of that variable as a key and when you printed the values you would call $row['Age']['George'] (ex.) and the correct value would pull. You will have to create and value the $firstName variable for this to work.

Comment: It still is not working. Perhaps you can show me how to put a counter variable starting at 0, and how to increment it with each loop. I updated my code in my question to what my code is currently.

Comment: before the loop begins, add a variable $counter = 0;  Then in the loop where you have ['Age'], make it ['Age'][$counter].  Right after your closing table tag, add a line reading $counter++;

Comment: It still doesn't work. I've added my updated code to the question. I'm going to delete all the table data and see if that will do anything.

Comment: I cleared the table data and input some new data. I found out that where it usually displays Age, it is displaying a random number or no number at all. Check it out: http://thetotempole.ca/phptester/editpage.php

Comment: Also, when I try to update an age I put in the code echo $sql."<br>"; and after I hit the update button it displays " UPDATE Persons SET Age=Array WHERE FirstName ='Array' " at the bottom of the page. Not sure if that's what it should be doing.

Comment: It shouldn't be.  You need to reference the array element within the post array element: $_POST['Age'][0].  Age is now an array, so you need to specify the element.  Do some research on multidimensional arrays, and I am sure you will see what I mean.

Comment: I am very new to this. I got this code from a different website. I honestly do not know where to go from here. I did look up multidimensional arrays, but I still do not have a clue.

Comment: Ok here is a phpfiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/40m-xn3.  Replace your code starting at <form> and ending at </form>.  If you use this code and it works for you, please credit me in the code in your application.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I'm going to find out how to make it so you don't have to type in the person's name in order for it to update.

Comment: You could always just echo $id into the entry field's value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrays:

```
<td><input type="text" name="person[<?php echo $row['FirstName'];?>]"></td>
```

and:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
foreach ($_POST['person'] as $id => $age)
{
  $sql="UPDATE Persons SET Age='".$age."' WHERE firstname ='".$id."'";
  $conn->query($sql) or die("Cannot update");//update or error
}
```

Also, don't forget mysql string escaping and html entities in FirstName in form input name.

Comment: I tried out your solution and it didn't solve my problem. I am trying what dsimer suggested and it seems that is not working either. It only works for the bottom input and it will update it correctly. When I try to update any other inputs it doesn`t work and displays the error "Cannot Update".

Comment: Try to check firstname column in db. You use both 'firstname' and 'FirstName'. Be sure that it's same in all places: in database table, in form input and in update sql query.

Comment: In the database table the column is FirstName. I changed all the firstnames I could find in my code and corrected the capitalization. I am still facing the same problem, though.

Comment: Add if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) var_dump($_POST); and post an output there.

Comment: You can also add echo $sql."<br>"; after "$sql=" and check if something is wrong with queries (running it in phpmyadmin).

Comment: Where do I put if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) var_dump($_POST); and what do you mean by posting an output? Sorry, I am new to PHP but I have to do this for my job. I added the echo statement to my page, though. I am not sure how you would check for something wrong in phpmyadmin.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
  var_dump($_POST);
  foreach ($_POST['person'] as $id => $age)
  {
   ....
  }
}

This should dump your form inputs when you click on Submit;

About mysql query - just run each one in phpmyadmin (SQL Query). It will show you details if there're errors.

Comment: Where do I put "if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) { var_dump($_POST); foreach ($_POST['person'] as $id => $age) { .... } }"? Do I have to replace "if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){//if the submit button is clicked" with it? Also, do I just copy and paste that in, or is there something I have to add into "if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) { var_dump($_POST); foreach ($_POST['person'] as $id => $age) { .... } }"? I figured out where the SQL Query is to search for the problem. Do I copy and paste my whole page's code into the SQL Query?